# Prevent the following objects from moving if the height increases in CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is a work of hiding and showing text.

In this study, hovering over the text above opens the text.

But when opening it moves the following.

In such a scenario
what do I need to do so that the following object does not move?

Can it be opened on it?

```css
.firstrow {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 18px;
    min-height: 36px
    max-height: 36px;
}
.firstrow:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: visible;
    line-height: 18px;
    min-height: 36px
    max-height: 108px;
}
.secondrow {
    background-color: #ededed;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstrow">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p> </div>

<div class="secondrow">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning on the bottom section to prevent it from moving at all and set the `z-index` of the first row so it overlaps the second. I don't know what your design intent is but that's pretty much the simple version of what you could do here. See also: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp  I also cleaned up your code a bit because you had a few issues and things you didn't need at all or were redundant.

```css
.firstrow {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 18px;
  max-height: 36px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.firstrow:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 108px;
}

.secondrow {
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstrow">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>

<div class="secondrow">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is as I requested and actually I am using the css codes here in the product titles and if the title is long the products slide down in the grid. This answer works for me, I'll try to implement it thanks.

Comment: @ersezar happy to help! If you could mark the check next to my answer to accept it I’d appreciate it :) Good luck with your project!